# Calendar/datepicker with color the available date

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to color the available date in my calendar datepicker [26-11-2015, 28-11-2015, 30-11-2015] I select.

Can someone help me ?

```js
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
     
     inline: true,
     dayNamesMin: [ "Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam" ],
     monthNames: [ "Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Auôt", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre" ],
     firstDay: 1,
     minDate: 0,
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var day = date.getDay();
            return [(day != +7)];
           /* var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ];*/
        },
     
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        // The hidden field to receive the date
        altField: "#dateHidden",
     prevText: '<',
        nextText: '>',
        // The format you want
        altFormat: "yymmdd",
        // The format the user actually sees
        dateFormat: "yymmdd",
     isRTL: false,
     showMonthAfterYear: false,
     yearSuffix: '',
        onSelect: selectDate, 
    });
```

Comment: Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS to change the colors.

Here is an example to change the color of available enabled dates:

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-state-default {
    color: deepskyblue;
    background: ghostwhite;
}
```

And for disabled dates:

```
.ui-datepicker td.ui-state-disabled>span {
    color: tomato;
}
```